# yii2 "подробные" ссылки

Tags: php, yii2

Я нет так давно работаю с `urlManager`ом и мне нужно сделать "подробную" ссылку, в общем мне нужно чтобы финальная ссылка выглядела [вот так](http://mysite/razdel_name/page_name) и как я предполагаю нужно передавать 2 параметра имя раздела, и имя страницы, кто работал с `yii2` так ли это??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Уберите комментарий в конфигурационном файле с секции urlManager.
Положите в web файл .htaccess следующего содержания

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Ссылку можно формировать так

```
Html::a('Link', ['controller/action', 'section' => 'section_titile', 'page' => 'page_titile']);
```

В urlManager правило может выглядеть так

```
'rules' => [
  '<section:[\w\-]+>/<page:[\w\-]+>' => 'controller/action'
]
```

Comment: Ну по поводу файла htaccess у меня это сделано, мне главное нужно было как формировать ссылку, ну принцип я понял, спасибо